# How to write my first Solidity "Hello World" smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment

I have never written a smart contract before because there is a lot attached to it getting it working. But I finally want to learn it now.

I want to write a simple mininmal working smart contract which prints out something or does something similar to saying "Hello World". Is that possible?

How would such a contract look like? How to deploy it, what tools do I need?

Comment: Here is a guide that worked for me. https://scbuergel.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/first-steps-in-ethereum/

Comment: This website have nice guide from with clear code and screenshots on how to get started: https://ethereumdev.io/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Greeter tutorial covers a basic Hello World contract. https://ethereum.org/greeter

As a quick summary, I just tested the following steps on Ubuntu 14.04. The install-geth script should also detect and work on other environments.

Note: I had to run the installation script in the first step below twice as it failed the first time.

- Install geth: `bash <(curl -L https://install-geth.ethereum.org)`
- Launch geth in developer mode so that we do not need to fetch the entire blockchain and can mine our own test-ether: `geth --dev console`
- Create a test account from geth console : `personal.newAccount()`
- Check your account balance (should be 0): `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`
- Start the miner and let it run: `miner.start()`
- Attach to geth via a second terminal session: `geth attach`
- Check that your account balance has increased: `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`
- Go to the online solidity compiler/editor at https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/. It defaults to a Greeter contract.
- Copy and paste the greeter's **Web3 deploy** code to a text editor and replace `/* var of type string here */` with "Hello World"
- Copy and paste the updated code to geth and wait for the *Contract mined!..* message
- Test the contract with `greeter.greet()`
- You can destroy the contract with `greeter.kill.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0]})`

Comment: This was using Ubuntu/Linux. What about other OS? I want to try it on Windows. Can you cover for all OS, new learners will be benefited from it a lot.