# What’s the role of the EVM in a plain ether transfer between Externally Owned Accounts?

Tags: transactions, evm, protocol

In a plain ether transfer from one Externally Owned Account to another, for which the base fee of 21000 gas has been provided, how is the EVM involved if at all? I realize that the signature needs to be verified, and of course the ether balance fields will have to be updated. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, no EVM instructions are needed at all - a transaction between two externally owned accounts transfers value directly, with no need to execute any code. Signature verification etc happens as part of the execution of the Ethereum system.

Comment: Wow, fascinating. But how is the EVM state updated if no EVM operations are performed? Or does the state update take place somewhere else outside of the EVM?

Answer (score 5):

The sending of a transaction from one Externally Owned Account (EOA) to another EOA does not involve the running of the EVM.

Here are my results from my testing.

I am running geth with `admin.verbosity(6)`.

Here are the debug logs from a transaction from one EOA to another EOA:

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
"0x2f2bc467573740ce8dc97cf4f929f49d741b24c55e43703ff7d313a359b8d890"
...
I0414 19:02:14.966112    6451 state_processor.go:83] receipt{med=e94a45839f1d47bf00779aa5d7546cbb8da06ac7c7eeeb98c27c2f98d773a4ec cgas=21000 bloom=0000000000000...000000000 logs=[]}
...
I0414 19:02:36.743200    6451 tx_pool.go:492] removed tx (
    TX(2f2bc467573740ce8dc97cf4f929f49d741b24c55e43703ff7d313a359b8d890)
    Contract: false
    From:     8d15cd39bdb00d5362775002c342c168ee707400
    To:       043f7fdc6e789060bfad91f7bba100d20a1cdf18
    Nonce:    4
    GasPrice: 20000000000
    GasLimit  90000
    Value:    1000000000000000000
    Data:     0x
    V:        0x1c
    R:        0x614fcf44cb76c056675c5929efb7cf2eb27d753f25b45eb74de868a9a9d62baa
    S:        0x339802b777fb88f699aa0a8dbbe48c7dcb95c8347aad70d87f3021dc291e43bb
    Hex:      f86d048504a817c80083015f9094043f7fdc6e789060bfad91f7bba100d20a1cdf18880de0b6b3a7640000801ca0614fcf44cb76c056675c5929efb7cf2eb27d753f25b45eb74de868a9a9d62baaa0339802b777fb88f699aa0a8dbbe48c7dcb95c8347aad70d87f3021dc291e43bb
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
```

And here are the debug logs from inserting the Greeter contract ([Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private)) into the blockchain - the EVM is executed:

```
I0414 19:06:58.157691    6451 vm.go:135] running byte VM 3551fd0f
I0414 19:06:58.158346    6451 vm.go:138] byte VM 3551fd0f done. time: 628.75µs instrc: 117
VM STAT 118 OPs
PC 00000000: PUSH1 GAS: 3940349 COST: 3
STACK = 0
MEM = 0
STORAGE = 0

PC 00000002: PUSH1 GAS: 3940346 COST: 3
STACK = 1
0000: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
MEM = 0
STORAGE = 0

PC 00000004: MSTORE GAS: 3940334 COST: 12
STACK = 2
0000: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
0001: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
MEM = 96
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0016: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0032: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

...
I0414 19:06:58.183560    6451 state_processor.go:83] receipt  {med=ab56da6288edf03204f3b9ad86ddfea3ec84bec3c21b173e6779768463ee8beb cgas=173426 bloom=00000...00000000 logs=[]}
```

---

EDIT: In response to the comment, I'm sending some extra data with the transaction.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), data:'0x12345678901234567890'})
"0x677ea32b0c4863727313c372d0e42b48b849d212fdb11e8dd7f5d2da4516bf6a"
...
I0414 19:20:16.172457    6573 state_processor.go:83] receipt{med=d973bd63b9151700e77aaee0db812d62997d219052bf84769ca43f4032e92df8 cgas=21680 bloom=000000...00000 logs=[]}
```

So no EVM involved even when extra data is sent with the transaction.

Comment: no evm even if you add a data in the transaction ? just curious ;)

Comment: To clarify further on the matter of attaching data to a transaction: either the recipient needs to be a contract, which has code *or* the recipient is empty, which creates a contract and executes the attached data as opcodes according to the EVM specification.

Comment: @JeffreyW. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there's nothing prohibiting you sending additional data to an EOA; it just won't do anything.

Comment: @NickJohnson you're correct, nothing is preventing you from doing so. Please bear in mind that adding extra data to a transaction will cost you *more* gas: non-zero value will cost you an additional `68` and a zero value will cost you an additional `4`. So the data `0xaa00aa` would cost you 140 gas.

Comment: This answer was very informative; taught me several things.