# In simple ether transfer type transaction, does the balance of the sending address gets debited instantly?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, balances

As per [What’s the role of the EVM in a plain ether transfer between Externally Owned Accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/what-s-the-role-of-the-evm-in-a-plain-ether-transfer-between-externally-owned-ac), one would expect that the sending account will get debited right after the transfer call. Yet, that does not happen. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think that the block chain has to be updated, and the my Geth instance has to download that block to see that there was a transfer and only then eth.getBalance call will return the new balance for the sending account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value will be debited from the sending account once the transaction is included in a block. Until then, while the transaction is in the mempool (pending inclusion in a block), geth maintains a temporary state which will also have decreased the balance, but which will only be returned by `getBalance` if you have mining activated.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it. I am not running Geth in mining mode, so`getBalance()` will not return the decreased amount. I have to wait till the sending transaction is included in a block and then `getBalance()` will return the decreased amount.