# Create contract in Go-ethereum with Solidity, "Hello world" program

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I want to create contract in go-ethereum using Solidity, I started with "Hello world" program.

I create a private network:

```
$geth --genesis private.json --networkid 1234 --datadir /home/user/Documents/genesisdata  console
```

In here, I make a new account then I coded follow link https://www.ethereum.org/greeter.

```
var greeterSource ='contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() returns (string) { return greeting; } function test() returns (string){ return greeting; } }'
```

And I got: **undefined**

When I code without **var** like this:

```
greeterSource ='contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() returns (string) { return greeting; } function test() returns (string){ return greeting; } }'
```

I got:

> "contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner =
>   msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner)
>   selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting;
>   function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; }
>   function greet() returns (string) { return greeting; } function test()
>   returns (string){ return greeting; } }"

So I continute code without **var**, I compile:

```
greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 210000}, function(e, contract){
if(!e) {

  if(!contract.address) {
    console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

  } else {
    console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
    console.log(contract);
  }

}
else{
console.log("Error:>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
console.log(e);
}
```

})

untill:

```
greeter.greet();
```

> TypeError: 'greet' is not a function
>       at :1:1

I don't know, how to solve it.

Please show me the problem that I make in this process.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a step-by-step guide: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private

Comment: I will try to @BokkyPooBah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem that you compiled the source? You just declared a variable holding the source code. That's the main problem.

Also, apparently, your function `greet()` is not declared with the keyword `constant`. You'll therefore have to call it with `greeter.greet.call()`

PS : no need to do this complicated stuff to create your development chain. Just run `get --dev --mine --minerthreads 1`

Comment: Yes, I do, I compiled the source and that is the result. I try: greeter.greet.call() and got "TypeError: Cannot access member 'call' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:1". #bortzmeyer

Comment: May be you do compile but it is not shown in your question. You should edit it for completeness.

Comment: And, after you compiled, you also have install the new contract, and gives the adress to the variable you want to use. This is clearly explained in the tutorial https://www.ethereum.org/greeter after the compilation step.

Comment: I wil check it again, thank you very much! @bortzmeyer

Answer (score 2):

`var greeterSource=...` is correct and Javascript throws this `undefined` at you every time. *Just ignore it*.
You can see that the variable was set correctly by typing `greeterSource` again.
You need to compile your contract with `solc` in order to use it, as the tutoral shows.

Comment: I follow step by step in tutoral and I compiled with **solc**.

Comment: could you have any idea or suggestion for my issue? I tried and strictly follow the tutorial. But my result always "TypeError: 'greet' is not a function at :1:1". Please help me