# Help needed - Contract is deployed but execution of method always returns Zero

Tags: solidity

I have created a private blockchain and trying to create a sample contract given in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions

I could create, compile and even deploy the contract but when I execute following statement:

```
myMultiply7.multiply.call(6)
```

It always returns "0".
Am I missing anything?

Steps I did:

1. Created a block chain.
2. Did some mining so that I can have some ether in my account. As it was a private network, I could get handsome amount of ether in my primary account.
3. Create and compiled contract in Geth Console as followed:

   ```
   primaryAccount = eth.accounts[0]

   source = "contract testA { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 5; } }"
   // compile with solc
   contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).testA
   // create contract object
   var MyContract = eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition)
   // extracts info from contract, save the json serialisation in the given file,
   //contenthash = admin.saveInfo(contract.info, "~/info.json")
   // send off the contract to the blockchain
   var mycon = MyContract.new({from: primaryAccount, data: contract.code}, function(error, contract){
       if(!error && contract.address) {
           console.log("Contract mined! address: " + contract.address + " transactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash);
       }
   });
   ```

Got the address as output but no transaction hash (Could this be a problem??).

Ran following :

```
var address = "<Address received in above code >";

var Multiply = web3.eth.contract([{constant:false,inputs:[{name:'a',type:'uint256'}],name:'multiply',outputs:[{name:'d',type:'uint256'}],type:'function'}]);
var myMultiply = Multiply.at(address);
myMultiply.multiply.call(9);
```

But last line always returns "0".

Unable to understand why this is happening. Am I missing certain steps? Do I need to do something else to get the contract executed?

Thanks in Advance..
Madhukar

Comment: please format the code better so it can be seen clearer

Comment: Your mining appears fine and you'd get a transaction hash the first time the callback is called, but your `if` condition is buggy so that's why you skip logging it: check the [example](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

Comment: A step-by-step guide to deploying a simple contract can be found at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private

Comment: I checked the if condition. It looks fine as I am getting the address part but transactionHash has no values. It is blank. How the transactionhash is generated? Am I missing anything else?

Comment: if condition should be revisited and improved

Answer (score 1):

> Got the address as output but no transaction hash (Could this be a problem??).

I deduce that you have not mined the contract and therefore it does not exist. If you are on a private net someone has to mine each transaction:

```
miner.start(); admin.sleepBlocks(1); miner.stop();
```

Comment: What do you mean someone has to mine? I am using a PC for testing and I am the one who is using the network. What is the way to simulate other user who can do mining?

Comment: > miner.start(); admin.sleepBlocks(1); miner.stop();