# Deploying Smart Contract into Ethereum testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mining, contract-deployment, testnets

I have followed this guide https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2787/2426 (or equivalently https://www.ethereum.org/greeter ) when trying to deploy a simple Smart Contract into Ethereum testnet. I am using geth CLI on testnet. Everything works except final step, uploading code at blockchain. This is what I did:

```
GETH SECOND INSTANCE:

geth --testnet --unlock 0 attach ipc:.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
    instance: Geth/v1.4.10-stable-5f55d95a/linux/go1.6.2
    coinbase: 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937
    at block: 1697809 (Mon, 26 Sep 2016 07:10:20 UTC)
     datadir: .ethereum/testnet
     modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]).toNumber(), "ether")
"5.024681313417504"
```

COMPILE:

```
> var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'

> var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
```

INSERT THE CONTRACT CODE INTO THE BLOCKCHAIN:

```
> var _greeting = "Good Morning, Smart Contract!"

> var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);

> var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting, {from: eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 4000000}, function(e, contract) { if (!e) { if (!contract.address) { console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined..."); } else { console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address); console.log(contract); } } })

> debug.verbosity(4)
```

When exploring greeter, this is the output:

```
> greeter
    {
      abi: [{
          constant: false,
          inputs: [],
          name: "kill",
          outputs: [],
          payable: false,
          type: "function"
      }, {
          constant: true,
          inputs: [],
          name: "greet",
          outputs: [{...}],
          payable: false,
          type: "function"
      }, {
          inputs: [{...}],
          type: "constructor"
      }],
      address: undefined,
      transactionHash: null
    }

> greeter.greet();
    TypeError: 'greet' is not a function
        at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I wait a minute and got no message like this:

```
Contract mined! address: 0x...
```

So, contract seems to be properly compiled but I cannot obtain nor address, nor txHash after uploading into blockchain. Maybe it's not been uploaded, or mined. **How can I figure it out? Did I miss something important?**

Edit: Right after trying to deploy log is reporting a lot of messages like this one:

```
I0926 10:31:13.097817 core/state/state_object.go:160] 47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937: #1048576 631783523629846744286 (+ 420000000000000)
```

Being 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937 the coinbase address of the geth node.

Comment: do you have enough test ether to deploy a contract?

Comment: I guess so, 5 ethers. Is that enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your command `geth --testnet --unlock 0 attach ipc:.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc` does not actually unlock the account. This command just attaches the console to the running `geth` instance.

If you had used `geth --testnet --unlock 0 console` instead, you will be asked to unlock your account with the following message:

```
Unlocking account 0 | Attempt 1/3
Passphrase: 
I0926 21:48:25.702979 cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:189] Unlocked account 3b44...a400
```

If you want to use the `geth ... attach` command, run the following command just before you execute your transactions:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "{your password}");
```

This will unlock your account and then enable the payment for the transaction.

Comment: Thx a lot. Now it works!