# How to execute Smart contracts on a private Blockchain network

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, blockchain, private-blockchain, remix

I have created a private Blockchain network on my Windows system with one node.  I have created accounts and was able to transfer ethers across them. Now I want to deploy smart contracts on this network, how should I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4):

easy task is to use solidity browser (local version) download it from the [github](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/tree/gh-pages).

1- unpack the zip and run the index.html

2-run your geth localy

3-configure solidity browser to use the private chain : under Environement tab (the Cube) choose Web3 Provider and set your RPC ip and port.

[image]

4- to deploy return back to the setting onglet and create the contract(means deploy it in the private chain)

[image]

5-to mine the transaction you will need to run the command miner.start() in your geth console, when done use miner.stop().

Comment: could we deploy contract from  geth?

Comment: @SigTouri - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9863/1268 or https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private for a step-by-step guide for deployment of contacts using `geth`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a Compiler installed.

Initialise your contract source.

Compile your contract source with using web3 or another RPC tool.

Create the contract object using web3 and an ABI definition.

Initialise a new instance of the Contract object with arguments and a dictionary with the account, code from the Compiled source, and gas amount, and a call back function.

Once you've initialised a new instance start mining.

You'll know that your contract has been successfully added to the blockchain once there is an address and a transaction hash for the contract.

If you don't see either, check two things. That the from account is unlocked and that the gas price is high enough.

check out the Ethereum example [here](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter).

Answer (score 1):

1)Go to [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js). You can write your solidity code there.

2) Now to deploy it in private network. Click on  **"Run"**, and there you can see **"Environment"**, from *drop down* choose **web3provider**, and add your RPC port number where your node is executing.

3)Now provide those parameters and click on **"create"**.
Now all you have to do is start mining in your geth console.
use

```
miner.start()
```

to start mining and

```
miner.stop()
```

to stop mining.

Your smart contract is Deployed in your private network.