# BigNumber error while trying to call structs

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js, testrpc

Consider the following contract:

```
contract Test{  
    uint public id;  
    address public addr;  
    bytes32 public name;  

    struct t {
     bytes32 name;
     uint id;
    address addr;  
   }  
   mapping (address => t) addr_map;
    function f1 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) {  
       id = param_1;  
       name = param_2;  
    }

   function f2 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) {  
      addr_map[msg.sender].name = param_2;  
      addr_map[msg.sender].id = param_1;  
   }  
}
```

I am using solc 0.4.4 and web3 calls to interact with the contract. Calling f1 no matter how much I try gives me an error (below the web3 snippet); however calling f1 doesnt have this issue - able to get the tx_hash.

```
testContractInstance.f2(1,"random",{from:accounts[0],gas:1000000}function(err,tx) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);} 
    console.log(tx)});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful. Error below:

> BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: new

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

- Replace `from:accounts[0]` with `from: web3.eth.accounts[0]` (or `from: eth.accounts[0]`), add a `,` before `function` and your code should work.

---

### Quick Code Check

Your code works perfectly in Browser Solidity:

[image]

---

### `geth` Deployment And Execution

#### Environment

```
Iota:Homebrew bok$ solc --version
Version: 0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.Darwin.appleclang
Iota:Homebrew bok$ geth version
Version: 1.4.18-stable-c72f5459
```

`geth` set up on a private chain as described in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9181/1268 .

#### Flatten your solidity code

I've flattened your code using `stripCrLf` from [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2610/1268) by saving the following code into Test.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test {  
    uint public id;  
    address public addr;
    bytes32 public name;

    struct t {
        bytes32 name;
        uint id;
        address addr;
    }  

    mapping (address => t) addr_map;

    function f1 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) {
       id = param_1;
       name = param_2;
    }

   function f2 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) {
      addr_map[msg.sender].name = param_2;
      addr_map[msg.sender].id = param_1;
   }
}
```

And

```
Iota:BigNumberError bok$ echo "var myTestSource='`stripCrLf Test.sol`'"
var myTestSource='pragma solidity ^0.4.4;contract Test {  uint public id;  address public addr; bytes32 public name; struct t { bytes32 name; uint id; address addr; }   mapping (address => t) addr_map;  function f1 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) { id = param_1; name = param_2; } function f2 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) { addr_map[msg.sender].name = param_2; addr_map[msg.sender].id = param_1; }}'
```

#### Run Your Code In `geth`

```
> var myTestSource='pragma solidity ^0.4.4;contract Test {  uint public id;  address public addr; bytes32 public name; struct t { bytes32 name; uint id; address addr; }   mapping (address => t) addr_map;  function f1 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) { id = param_1; name = param_2; } function f2 (uint param_1, bytes32 param_2) returns (bool) { addr_map[msg.sender].name = param_2; addr_map[msg.sender].id = param_1; }}'
undefined
> var myTestCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(myTestSource);
undefined
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "aaaargh");
true
> var myTestContract = web3.eth.contract(myTestCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
var myTest = myTestContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: myTestCompiled.Test.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0xc1516f0ab41f20ac705df2645b361fc0438f94470942cf6c14381f1d6ffe9148 waiting to be mined...
undefined
> Contract mined! Address: 0x073cc4149857145d1898dd91ef24c3a767929f5f
[object Object]
> myTest.f1(1, "random", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000}, function(err, tx) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    console.log(tx)
});
> myTest.id()
1
> web3.toAscii(myTest.name().toString());
"random\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
>     myTest.f2(2, "random 2", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000}, function(err, tx) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    console.log(tx)
});
0xf8814a2e1466b8c55041b6df95a55495616491e035e50dfd3a0039d367678de4
undefined
> myTest.f2(2, "random 2", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000}, function(err, tx) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    console.log(tx)
});
0xf8814a2e1466b8c55041b6df95a55495616491e035e50dfd3a0039d367678de4
undefined
```

All seems to work with the correct function parameters.

#### Looking For Your Error Message

I tried using `accounts[0]` instead of `eth.accounts[0]` in my function call and got the following message:

```
myTest.f2(2, "random 2", {from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000}, function(err, tx) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    console.log(tx)
});
ReferenceError: 'accounts' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:37
```

Not the same error message as you got.

I tried removing the `,` before the function but it does not give the same error message as you got:

```
> myTest.f2(2, "random 2", {from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000} function(err, tx) {
......     if (err) {
.........         console.log(err);
.........     } 
......     console.log(tx)
......     });
(anonymous): Line 1:64 Unexpected token function (and 2 more errors)
> myTest.f2(2, "random 2", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000} function(err, tx) {
......     if (err) {
.........     console.log(err);
.........    } 
......     console.log(tx)
...... });
(anonymous): Line 1:68 Unexpected token function (and 2 more errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This seems to happen if your node wasn't fully synced**. perhaps you try to communicate with a contract which is not synced yet. so try to sync with the blockchain and retry.

read :https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/434

I've tried your contract and the following snipet in web3js and it works fine :

```
 contractInstance.f2(1,"random",{from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:1000000},function(err,tx) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);} 
    console.log(tx)});
```

it returns the transaction hash

[image]