# Can't use object of web3.eth.compile.solidity(source)

Tags: web3js, meteor

I have the following code (source is the solidity contract to be compiled).

```
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
var code = compiled.code;
var abi = compiled.info.abiDefinition;
```

However `compiled.code` and `compiled.info.abiDefinition` return undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes `undefined` gets printed to the console, but the code has still worked; have you checked typing `abi` into the console afterwards to check?

Comment: This is what i get. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abiDefinition' of undefined` however if i print in the console `console.log(JSON.stringify(compiled))` it is not undefined

Comment: what is printed for `compiled`?

Comment: {"<stdin>:demo":{"code":" too long for comment ","info":{"source":"contract demo { string public name = 'Petros'; function changeName(string _newName) constant returns (string d){ name = _newName; }}","language":"Solidity","languageVersion":"0.4.9","compilerVersion":"0.4.9","compilerOptions":"--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize","abiDefinition":[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":

Comment: [{"name":"_newName","type":"string"}],"name":"changeName","outputs":[{"name":"d","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}],"userDoc":{"methods":{}},"developerDoc":{"methods":{}}}}}

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/go-ethereum-greeter-tutorial-unable-to-define-greetercontract which describes the same problem and provides a work-around.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah Still have the same problem

Comment: @BokkyPooBah There was a whole bunch of stuff and i missed the answer. I will post it to be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update Apr 23 2017

`geth` 1.6.0 has a breaking change to remove access to the Solidity compiler from within `geth`.

The workaround is detailed in [How to compile Solidity contracts within geth with the v1.6.0 **BREAKING CHANGE**?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-within-geth-with-the-v1-6-0-breaking-change)

---

This works..

```
var source = 'contract demo {string public name = "Petros"; function changeName(string _newName){name = _newName; } }'; 
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
var abi = compiled['<stdin>:demo'].info.abiDefinition;
```