# How to compile Solidity contracts with Geth v1.6?

Tags: solidity, compilation

I tried to compile the following contract within `geth`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
    uint256 public value;

    function Test() {
        value = 123;    
    }
}
```

using the following commands on the flattened source:

```
> var testSource = "pragma solidity ^0.4.8; contract Test { uint256 public value; function Test() { value = 123; } }";
undefined
> var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
Error: The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:20
```

As described in [eth_compilers, eth_compileSolidity are gone in go-ethereum 1.6.0 #3793](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793), the ability to compile Solidity source has been removed from within `geth`.

How can I compile my Solidity source code?

Comment: how to compiling token system coins guide me any one

Comment: See https://github.com/bokkypoobah/Tokens#seantest-token-on-ropsten for method to use Remix and MyEtherWallet to deploy token contracts

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Alternative 1 - Use Remix To Compile, Then Copy-Paste To Deploy

Use Remix from https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity:

[image]

Copy the Web3 deployment instructions from the Remix page:

```
var untitled_testContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"value","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var untitled_test = untitled_testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x60606040523415600b57fe5b5b607b6000819055505b5b608f806100246000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680633fa4f24514603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b6047605d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600054815600a165627a7a72305820a4fac284b98d43538f802082b0db8c67ddd6d72df4e8d9fbccb4cec0e52ea0df0029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

And paste it into the `geth console` with an unlocked account:

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "{top secret password}");
true
> var untitled_testContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"value","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
"0xe22dc29e3e05d3206d9636ae7cba87a2827e7b3ef28c6e8e6d2ad49a14ba3ce9"
var untitled_test = untitled_testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
     data: '0x60606040523415600b57fe5b5b607b6000819055505b5b608f806100246000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680633fa4f24514603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b6047605d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600054815600a165627a7a72305820a4fac284b98d43538f802082b0db8c67ddd6d72df4e8d9fbccb4cec0e52ea0df0029',
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

---

#### Alternative 2 - Use Solidity Compiler (Linux and OS/X, maybe Windows With Cygwin)

```
$ more Test.sol 
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
    uint256 public value;

    function Test() {
        value = 123;    
    }
}
```

Compile Test.sol in the .json format, assign the data to a JavaScript variable and send the output into a file:

```
$ echo "var testOutput=`solc --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,interface Test.sol`" > test.js
$ cat test.js
var testOutput={"contracts":{"Test.sol:Test":{"abi":"[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"value\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"constructor\"}]","bin":"60606040523415600b57fe5b5b607b6000819055505b5b608f806100246000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680633fa4f24514603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b6047605d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600054815600a165627a7a72305820d0e71d151634ac6ae7626860a17881104022e5cd6d3a088eb8f941d9aa8e3bd20029"}},"version":"0.4.9+commit.364da425.Darwin.appleclang"}
```

In `geth`, load the contents of test.js:

```
$ geth console
...
> loadScript("test.js")
true
> testOutput
{
  contracts: {
    Test.sol:Test: {
      abi: "[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"value\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"constructor\"}]",
      bin: "60606040523415600b57fe5b5b607b6000819055505b5b608f806100246000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680633fa4f24514603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b6047605d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600054815600a165627a7a72305820d0e71d151634ac6ae7626860a17881104022e5cd6d3a088eb8f941d9aa8e3bd20029"
    }
  },
  version: "0.4.9+commit.364da425.Darwin.appleclang"
}

> testOutput.contracts
{
  abi: "[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"value\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"constructor\"}]",
...
> var testContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(testOutput.contracts["Test.sol:Test"].abi));
undefined
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "{top secret password}");
true
> var test = testContract.new({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + testOutput.contracts["Test.sol:Test"].bin, gas: 4700000},
  function (e, contract) {
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
  }
);
...
```

Comment: If I follow your instructions from Alternative 1 I get the error: "err: Error: invalid argument 0: invalid hex". I figured out that the bytecode (bin) causes this error. I also tried Alternative 2 but I get the same error.

Comment: Alternative 2 worked and was the only working instruction I could find so far. Big thanks!

Comment: I was able to compile contract with https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ but when i got code from field WEB3DEPLOY and paste it in https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts  Deploy contract filed it throw an error (red borders)

Comment: In a newer version of remix click on "Details" button of "Compile" section and look for `WEB3DEPLOY` section

Answer (score 7):

I've encountered the same issue recently.  There are a variety of workarounds, but here is the method I've employed.  This isn't necessarily the best approach.

To generate bytecode:

`> solc --bin soliditySource.sol`

To generate ABI:

`> solc --abi soliditySource.sol`

Then, with your newly generated `bytecode` and `abi`, in geth 1.6:

```
 var abi = <abi from solc>;
 var myContract = eth.contract(abi); 
 var bytecode = '0x' + <bytecode from solc>;
 var txDeploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data: bytecode, gas: 1000000}; 
 var myContractPartialInstance = myContract.new(txDeploy); 

 // Mine block containing transaction...

 var myContractInstance = myContract.at(myContractPartialInstance.address);
```

Comment: The abi needs to be a JSON object, so convert with `JSON.parse`.  Also the account might need to be unlocked first with eg. `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll consider downloading the `truffle` framework instead. With the truffle framework, I'm able to compile but also store my files easily (it does it for me).

Once you have downloaded `truffle` with the command

`npm i -g truffle`

you can easily compile using the command `truffle compile`.

Answer (score 3):

After bashing my head against out of date docs for a few days, I've made a super simple version here that might help: https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I've posted your link at https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/6ouis7/first_steps_with_ethereum_private_networks_and/

Comment: Thanks @BokkyPooBah, hope it helps people. The official docs are pretty dreadful.

Answer (score 0):

Because geth deprecated the command-line compiler interface after version 1.6, I was puzzled for a long time.I wrote a simple tutorial to describe how to compile and deploy a contract after geth1.6.
Hope this tutorial will help you.
[Depoly contract on the private chain](http://blog.csdn.net/weixin_40401264/article/details/78136346)

Answer (score 0):

Building a smart contract using the command line
https://www.ethereum.org/greeter

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange. Please do not post questions as answers to other questions. If you need assistance with a problem, please post a new question and someone will hopefully answer it.