# How to create the contracts on ethereum?

Tags: ether, tokens

I need to create the ethereum tokens for this i learn about contracts. I try with simple contract using this link https://www.ethereum.org/greeter

when i try this contract

eth.getCompilers()

var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'

var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)

the above line got the error like this

Error: The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available

Then we search about this error. the functions are depricated on the latest version

so how we can create this contracts. I can't get the correct solution for this on online so please help anyone

Thanks in advance

Comment: New version of geth do not have the compiler installed, see this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-with-geth-v1-6

Answer (score 2):

I probably think in latest version you cannot compile solidity directly. I am not sure of this. 
Try using online solidity compiler. This is much better way.

https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/

(This is the link for solidity online compiler)
[image: This is one such contract]

after writing your contract you will get *bytecode, interface and web3 deploy*.
copy the code in web3 deploy to some directory you wish, lets say to *$HOME/Desktop/contract/ballot.js*

start you geth console and simply do a load script i.e in your geth console type *loadScript('PATH')*

Here is *PATH* is the relative path of ballot.js