# The Solc Compiler on OSX - Hello World

Tags: cpp-ethereum, solc

I'm trying to do the hello world app seen here https://www.ethereum.org/greeter#compiling-your-contract.

It says I should be able to do `eth.getCompilers()`

> The first you can get by using a compiler. You should have a solidity
>   compiler built in on your geth console. To test it, use this command:

So I have geth installed, but how am I supposed to do `eth.getCompilers()`? I'm I missing some install? My geth version is `Version: 1.6.5-stable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been known for a while that the normal hello world example is broken.
See: [Alternative to deprecated Greeter example code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/alternative-to-deprecated-greeter-example-code)

One thing he mentions is `solc` which is the command for `Solidity`, a compiler that takes the Javascript-esque `Solidity` language and compiles it to byte code for the `Ethereum Virtual Machine` (EVM).

Comment: Do you know of any "hello world" ethereum projects that do have good directions?