# Can someone help me get started on the Ethereum platform like all the basics?

Tags: go-ethereum

Im looking to get started in the cryptocurrency field and expand my knowledge in Ethereum

Comment: This is not really a question but a statement. It should be edited to be a more specific question because it is too broad in scope. That said, you might find some of the information that you are looking for in the following post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-would-i-explain-ethereum-to-a-non-technical-friend/

Answer (score 3):

I started with the help of following links and tutorials, that may help you as well. My aim was to learn Ethereum and blockchain basics and then start DApp development quickly.

- Blockchain Whitepaper:  http://scet.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/BlockchainPaper.pdf
- MIT resources on Blockchain: http://blockchain.mit.edu/
- Blockchain essential course by IBM: https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/blockchain-essentials/
- Ethereum Whitepaper: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper
- Geth:  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum (one of the Ethereum Client)
- Solidity Documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ (Go through with it before writing smart contracts)
- DLT Labs YouTube video on Ethereum Basics -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yZ7037M_Lc
- Udemy Course of Ethereum DApp development(10$ only) - https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-developer/
- Videos from Jordan Leigh - https://youtu.be/8jI1TuEaTro, https://youtu.be/3-XPBtAfcqo

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new and learning too :)

You can start with getting your dev environment setup by following this: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac

Just a heads up, in your research, you might find the Greeter example: https://www.ethereum.org/greeter . But to save you some frustration, the code is deprecated and no longer works! I have a question already posted around this: [Alternative to deprecated Greeter example code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/alternative-to-deprecated-greeter-example-code) . But you can see if you can get as far as I did! The one answer, which wasn't what I was looking for, might be a route you are willing to take.

Good luck! And if you find any other useful walkthroughs/documentation, pm me, and/or list back on this thread!