# How do i get Bytecode of the contract to deploy?

Tags: contract-deployment, remix, bytecode

I read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-with-geth-v1-6#_=_)
but still cannot figure out how to deploy contract.

What i need: deploy smart-contract to Ethereum network via web-based wallet - [Myetherwallet, menu Contracts](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) where there are 2 fields; Byte code and Gas limit.I need to get the Byte code  to paste.

What I've done,

1. Get contract code from [here](https://gist.github.com/FerumFlex/1e35b45e13bf3fcadc45e2ae46245451).
2. Paste it in [here](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.js)   and got WEB3DEPLOY code, where some parameters need, for example address, _startBlock and others.

.

```
var _startBlock = /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var _endBlock = /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var _rate = /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var _wallet = /* var of type address here */ ;
var browser_untitled_sol_crowdsaleContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"endBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"rate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"weiRaised","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"startBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"wallet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"beneficiary","type":"address"}],"name":"buyTokens","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"hasEnded","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"token","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_startBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_endBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_rate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_wallet","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"purchaser","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"beneficiary","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TokenPurchase","type":"event"}]);
var browser_untitled_sol_crowdsale = browser_untitled_sol_crowdsaleContract.new(
   _startBlock,
   _endBlock,
   _rate,
   _wallet,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

So, how do i get bytecode of the contract to deploy?
Why: Ethereum wallet sync takes too much time...

Answer (score 8):

Go to [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and paste your code there.
In the "Compile" tab, select the contract you want and click on "Details" and you can copy ABI, Bytecode, etc...

That being said, I find it way easier to deploy your contracts straight from Remix with Metamask.
Make sure you are connected to the right network/account in Metamask, then go to the "Run" tab, make sure the "Injected Web3" environment is selected.
Select your contract in the dropdown menu, and click on "Create" (if necessary, pass the constructor arguments in the text box next to "Create" first)

This will show you a Metamask dialog to accept the transaction.
After this, your deployed contract will show up in this tab and you can interact with it.