# Error when trying to create new Solidity contract using Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix

Very new to Geth and Ethereum, and I'm just trying to create my first contract and deploy it to my private blockchain using Geth.

Geth version 1.7.3

Below is my Solidity contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
uint256 public value;

function Test() {
    value = 123;    
}
}
```

I have compiled this contract with the browser compiler and Copying the Web3 deployment instructions from the Remix browser compiler into geth console, and I have also tried using the built in solidity compiler on my mac to compile and create a new contract.  i'll note I'm not compiling from inside geth console, as I know that doesn't work anymore, I keep getting the error when I call:

```
testContract.new(<ContractCode>)
```

Below is the output of the code I run with the compiled contract with the error:

```
var test = testContract.new({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + testOutput.contracts["Test.sol:Test"].bin, gas: 18000000000},
function (e, contract) {
  console.log(e, contract);
  if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
  var test = testContract.new({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + 
  testOutput.contracts["Test.sol:Test"].bin, gas: 18000000000},
    function (e, contract) {
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
  }
});
Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined
```

Comment: I've done a lot of research on this issue.  I have tried to start my geth node using " --targetgaslimit " with an exorbitantly high value and that still gives me the "Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined"

Comment: LINK TO STACKEXCHANGE ANSWER I WAS TRYING   https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-with-geth-v1-6/15436?newreg=5b121518d1d247b084306f33c76adadb

Answer (score 0):

If your error is in geth, then I can recommend you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/deploying-a-smart-contract-the-hard-way-8aae778d4f2a) about Deploying A Smart Contract. Be sure to [set your private chain](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html) **correct**, to have account, to have balance `>0`, to `unlockAccount` before deploying contract.

*As you've mentioned in your question that you are new to geth. It might be helpful to point that before you dive into deploying smart contracts in geth, be sure to read some articles on how to set up ethereum node using geth. Hope that will help!*