# Can't use object "compiled" in var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js, meteor

I've been struggling for the past couple of days with this. I Can't use object "compiles" in `var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);`
Here is my code in a JS file :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var source = 'contract demo {string public name = "Petros"; function changeName(string _newName){name = _newName; } }'; 
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
var abi = compiled.info.abiDefinition;
```

But i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined` If I output compiled to console `console.log(JSON.stringify(compiled));` I get the following:

```
{"<stdin>:demo":{"code":"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",
"info":{"source":"contract demo {string public name = \"Petros\"; function changeName(string _newName){name = _newName; } }",
"language":"Solidity","languageVersion":"0.4.9","compilerVersion":"0.4.9",
"compilerOptions":"--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
"abiDefinition":[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newName","type":"string"}],"name":"changeName","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}],
"userDoc":{"methods":{}},"developerDoc":{"methods":{}}}}}
```

I am using meteor version 1.4.2.5, Geth version: Geth/v1.5.8-stable-f58fb322/linux/go1.7.3
, Solc Version: 0.4.9+commit.364da425.Linux.g++, OS: Linux mint
I run my geth node with this command: `geth --rpc --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:3000" --testnet`

Comment: what is the result of web3.version.api ?

Comment: console.log(web3.version.api );  =  0.18.2

Comment: I don't have a solution that I've tested (downgrade solc? upgrade web3? wait for an upgrade of web3?) but solc has changed the format of its json output from having <contract name> as key to having </path/to/contract>:<contract name>, which is causing lots of tooling to explode.

Comment: More info here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/unable-to-define-greetercontract-in-the-greeter-tutorial-breaking-change-in-sol/11915#11915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update Apr 23 2017

`geth` 1.6.0 has a breaking change to remove access to the Solidity compiler from within `geth`.

The workaround is detailed in [How to compile Solidity contracts within geth with the v1.6.0 **BREAKING CHANGE**?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-within-geth-with-the-v1-6-0-breaking-change)

---

I had the same problem.

It's caused by the compiler inserting <stdin>:ContractName in the output object.

Use the following to access the abi definition.

> var abi = compiled['<stdin>:demo'].info.abiDefinition;