# Ethereum Contract Deployment

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ubuntu, greeter, golang

```
var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);
```

I am getting this type of error on geth console:

> TypeError:Cannot access member 'info' of undefined at :1:41

[I follow this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private/2787#2787), can I add any system dependencies, I think golang is by default available in Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like an issue with a recent breaking change that's breaking a lot of examples. Have a look at this Q&A. Same issue? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/unable-to-define-greetercontract-in-the-greeter-tutorial-breaking-change-in-sol/11915#11915