# Greeter Contract - deploy command results in "undefined"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, greeter

I am trying to deploy the Greeter contract on a private test chain following this guide ([Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private))

When I get to the `"var greeter ="` command pasted below, it runs but only ever returns `"undefined"`, it does not look like the contract ever deploys.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please

thanks,
P

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting, {from: eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].code, gas:20000000000}, function(e, contract) { 
  if (!e) { 
   if (!contract.address) { 
     console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined..."); 
   } else { 
     console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address); console.log(contract); 
   } 
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable declarations will return `undefined`. Its not an error.

In order to get contract address you need to mine in your private network. Make sure that your are mining.

Comment: Hi Gokulnath, thank you for the reply. I do understand that undefined is not an error, however I expected to see output "Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address".  I am mining, so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I have failed to unlock the account `eth.account[0]` (which I was using to deploy the contract), prior to attempting to deploy the contract.

After running `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0]);` the contract successfully deployed!